# Why does a bash redirection happen *before* the command starts, if the ">" is after the command?

Tags: bash

Recently I tried to list all of the images located in a directory I had (several hundred) and put them into a file. I used a very simple command

```
ls > "image_names.txt"
```

I was bored and decided to look inside the file and realized that *image_names.txt* was located in the file. Then I realized, the order of operations performed was not what I thought. I read the command as left to right, in two separate steps:

1. `ls` *(First list all the file names)*
2. `> "image_names.txt"` *(Then create this file and pipe it here)*

Why is it creating the file **first** then listing all of the files in the directory, despite the `ls` command coming first?

Comment: This isn't bash-specific at all -- the POSIX sh standard requires that *all* compliant shells behave this way. In the very beginning of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html, redirections are step 5, whereas execution is step 6 -- which is to say, the redirections *always* happen before execution.

Comment: `if the ">" is after the command?` who said that? `> "image_names.txt" ls` is completely valid

Answer (score 2):

When you use output redirection, the shell needs a place to put your output( suppose it was very long, then it could all be lost on terminate, or exhaust all working memory), so the first step is to open the output file for streaming output from the executed command's stdout.

This is especially important to know in this kind of command

```
cat a.txt | grep "foo" > a.txt
```

since a is opened first and not in append mode it will be truncated, meaning there is no input for `cat`.  So the behaviour you expect that the lines will be filtered from a.txt and replace a.txt will not actually happen.  Instead you will just lose the contents of `a.txt`.

Comment: The only part I am stuck on in reading your explanation is the word "truncated", I have tried googling it with not so helpful definitions.

Great answer though, ty.

Comment: Further, the example is an *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat` -- or Unwise Use Of `cat`). I take your point to be you cannot both read from and write to the same file without using a temporary file in the interim. Your example without the UUOc would be `grep "foo" a.txt > a.txt` which would not work without using a `List`, e.g. `grep "foo" a.txt > tmp; mv -f tmp a.txt`

Comment: @J.Doe "Truncated" means the end is cut off. In this case, it happens to be truncated starting right at the beginning, which basically means the file's contents are erased. BTW, there's another complication: `ls *.txt >textfiles.txt` will *not* list textfiles.txt in the output, because the shell is responsible for wildcard expansion, and it does this during its parsing phase, before any part of the command actually gets executed.

Comment: That command has a race condition because each part of the pipeline runs in parallel (and redirections are per stage). You won't know whether the file is truncated first or whether it's partially or fully read first.

Answer (score 0):

Because redirection `> "image_names.txt"` was performed before `ls` command.